# CRC8 Python Code, How to convert a list into CRC8 values?

Tags: python, crc, crc8

There are errors(syntax and many more), when i convert a list into crc8 hash values.
I want to convert a list into CRC8 hash values. Please have a look

```
import crc8
hash = crc8.crc8()
hash.update(b'123')
assert hash.hexdigest() == 'c0'
assert hash.digest() == b'\xc0'
```

This is the sample code to convert string into crc8 hash values.
I want to convert a list into hash values. Each item in the list needs to be converted into hash values.

```
import crc8
list = b["ya123","hello123","nihao123"]
for i in list:
   hash = crc8.crc8()
   hash.update(i)
   assert hash.hexdigest() == 'c0'
   assert hash.digest() == b'\xc0'
```

Output of conversion should look like this

```
["0x66","0xBF","0x1A"]
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please reword your question in order to describe a more precise issue, where you state your goal, what you tried (I guess you posted that part: your code), and what doesn't match your expectation : "I want to do [this ...]. I tried [this ...]. I expected [this ...] but I got [this ...] instead"

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I want to transform a list into CRC8 hash values.

Comment: Did you notice the syntax error when you tried running this? Why would you seemingly expect the hexdigest to be equal to "c0" for three different values?

Comment: @Vlad, I am a beginner, Perhaps I made mistake.

Comment: No problem, we all were beginners once. However, it's difficult to answer a vague question. What results do you want? What are the results you get? Do you want to hash all values in turn and generate a list of CRC values? Or do you want to concatenate the values and hash that? Please, as a new user, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, if you want to improve your question, you can [edit] it instead of adding the missing info in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The crc8 class requires bytes - not strings. Therefore:

```
from crc8 import crc8

lst = [b'yas123', b'nihao123', b'hello123']
output = [hex(ord(crc8(e).digest())) for e in lst]
print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
['0xb3', '0x1a', '0xbf']
```

**Note:**

Not sure why the expected output is as stated in the question

**Alternative implementation:**

```
from crc8 import crc8

lst = ['yas123', 'nihao123', 'hello123']
output = [hex(ord(crc8(e.encode()).digest())) for e in lst]
print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks, mate. you have solved the problem. What if I have long list (1000 +, elements in the list) . I think, I can not convert list into bytes like lst = bytes(lst)  , because it only take integer values in the list, but not the string

Comment: @YasirGlani See alternative implementation in the answer